# How do I access RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute?

Tags: vb.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Web Forms app that I created a few months ago and I added a Web API controller. I tried to use the 'automatic' routing that I saw in a presentation recently, but all I got was a 404. Then I tried to add routing for the Web API controller in my Global.asax using MapHttpRoute, as I've seen in several tutorials. However, even after adding `Imports System.Web.Http` to the file, the project will not recognize `RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute()` I have tried adding other namespaces and ensuring that I have all the necessary Nuget packages, but I still am unable to set up routing for the Web API controller. Does anyone have a recommendation of where to start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1819836.aspx), which indicates that IntelliSense apparently has a problem with this, but if you type something like the following, it will build and run:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyApi", "api/{controller}")
```

Answer (score 17):

If anyone has this same issue in C# read on.

I am also using a web forms app and set the routing through the `Global.asax` file. For me Intellisense was 100% correct and it would not build regardless. To get this to work I had to add the following using directives.

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

and

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Becareful **not** to use `using System.Web.Http.Routing` by accident. This wont work.

Comment: You appear to be using C# whereas my project uses VB, so that may explain the difference.

Comment: Good point. I didnt notice the vb tag. I'll edit this answer in case any other C# user can get some value from it.

Comment: Thanks, this question is pretty high on Google results for MapHttpRoute. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 11):

You should add the reference to **System.Web.Http.WebHost** assembly and make sure you have

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

Why ? **MapHttpRoute** is defined in two assemblies, in `System.Web.Http`:

```
public static System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute MapHttpRoute(
    this System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection routes, string name, string routeTemplate)
```

Member of `System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollectionExtensions`

and in `System.Web.Http.WebHost`

```
public static Route MapHttpRoute(
    this RouteCollection routes, string name, string routeTemplate, object defaults);
```

First one is an Extension on **HttpRouteCollection**

Second one is an Extension on **RouteCollection**

**So when you have a webforms app, your Routes are defined in a `RouteCollection` so you need the `WebHost` version.**

Its because architecture allowing WebApi to be hosted also out of IIS. see [Hosting WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api)

Comment: Edited answer to be a bit clearer.  This is what tripped me up, I had found the `MapHttRoute` but it wasn't for `RouteCollection`

Answer (score 1):

I've just created two new webforms apps (one using .NET 4, the other 4.5), did nothing more than add web api via nuget and it worked.

What version of ASP.NET is your app running in? If you're running ASP.NET WebForms 2.0/3.5 then it's not supported.

Here's a tutorial which demonstrates how to add Web API to your Web Forms app - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using .NET 4.5 with Visual Studio 2012. That tutorial is actually one that I've been looking at, but when I get to the "Add Routing Information" step, I'm unable to set up the routing.

Comment: @probackpacker How bizarre.

If you look at the actual references for your web app project, can you see System.Web.Http and System.Web.Http.WebHost listed?

Comment: Yes, both of those are listed in the references for the project.

Comment: Reference to System.Web.Http.WebHost solved my problem. Thanks @WilliamL

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case, I solved by creating the api controller, when you add the
api controller VS will load all required refrences.